# Assign Values of one array to another having different property names in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array with Name "Array1" and which contains two properties "key", "value" and i have another array with name "Array2" which has two properties "Text", "Value"

How can i assign the values of "Array1" to "Array2"

Which i mean i want the values of "key" property in "Array1" to "Text" property of "Array2" also "value" property in "Array1" in "Value" property of "Array2"

I want to achieve this in Angular 6 or 7 typescript.

Comment: Please add the following to your question: A json example of Array1, a json example of Array2 and a json example of your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
let arr1 = [
    { key: "1", value: "2017-01-24" },
    { key: "2", value: "2017-01-22" }
];

let arr2 = [
    { test: "3", value: "ab" },
    { test: "4", value: "abc" }
];

let arr3  = arr1.concat(arr2); 
  
for(i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++){
  if(arr3[i]['key']){
     arr3[i].test = arr3[i]['key'];
    delete arr3[i].key;
  }
}
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = [
  { key: 'a', value: "1" },
  { key: 'b', value: "2" },
  { key: 'c', value: "3" }
];

const array2 = [
  { key: 'a', text: 'x' },
  { key: 'b', text: 'y' },
  { key: 'c', text: 'z' }
];

array.forEach(a => {
  const b = array2.find(x => x.key === a.key);
  if (b) {
    b.text = a.value;
  }
});
```

Is this what you want? It loops through each value in array 1, finds the matching value in array2 (matching on "key"), and then copies the value from "value" to "text".

Please add some example code to clarify your question if I have misunderstood.

Comment: You may want to use `Array#map` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map  to convert object of one type to another.  I think the OP requires the `key` field to be converted to `text` field.

Comment: I doubt he actually means an array, because he mentions keys and values. I think he just means a simple object. Which could be solved with `Object.assign`, but that's just guessing.

Comment: This is the problem with poor questions and lazy posters. Don't know why we waste our time sometimes

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Worked fine for me